# How to control a DC motor with mini Lab 1008 usb and LabVIEW

Tags: controls, port, labview

I am in an internship and unfamiliar with LabVIEW, and am having trouble figuring out how to output the pc +5 volts though LabVIEW to control a DC motor. If you can help with example program, that will of be great help.

Comment: Your question is too vague for anyone (except your tutors) to answer properly. Your title mentions USB, however the question does not mention the USB. What kind of DC motor do you have, what kind of DAQ do you have? Which motor do you have, and does is come with examples (.net, C, LabVIEW).
You mention the 5V output, you can get 5V of you USB port, however *DO NOT DO THIS*. It might harm your computer and/or your motor, the USB does not have a lot of power.

Comment: the DaQ in use is a mini lab 1008 usb and i wish to output a voltage on one of its ports to power a dc motor with max out of 5volt dc motor

Comment: The specs for the 1008 say it can supply 450 mA from its +5 V output terminal, powered by the USB host. This might be enough to run a small motor. You'll need a drive circuit though (see my comment below Ton's answer) and if I were doing this I'd make sure I used a drive circuit that included over-current protection...

Answer (score 2):

National Instruments has very good manuals especially for newbies.
You can easily find on their website tutorials how to start playing with LabVIEW and with measurements like these:

[Introduction to NI LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/gettingstarted/labviewbasics/) or [Getting Started with NI-DAQmx: Getting Started with NI-DAQmx Programming in LabVIEW](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/5468)

And as I know the have very good support too so you can call them for additional help.

Comment: DAQmx will do no good here since the device is not manufactured by NI.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [page](http://www.mccdaq.com/daq-software/universal-library-extensions-lv.aspx) that includes a set of drivers for the mini 1008 including examples. Have a look at these drivers and examples.

Comment: Further to this helpful answer, I found the [datasheet](http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/specs/minilab-1008-spec.pdf) for the mini 1008 which shows that its outputs can only drive a few milliamps - so as well as this device you are going to need a motor drive circuit to switch the power to the motor based on the outputs from the 1008. If you search the web for 'H-bridge motor controller' you'll find lots of circuits as well as kits and ready-built modules for sale.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the analogue output of the mini 1008 to control the speed of the motor, which would need a different type of drive circuit.